# Is there any profiling tool to measure web application performance by identifying common interactions paths?

Tags: analytics, web-applications, sql, profiling, logs

I would like to measure how long it takes to complete a single operation such as "UPDATING AGE ON A CUSTOMER FORM", "INSERT A NEW CUSTOMER" in my web application. Is there any tool with some web server log grouping feature that let me build my interaction group and then recognize the same pattern in future logs?

Answer (score 1):

You can monitor the performance of the entire service as well as narrow down server-side SQL query's using [New Relic](http://www.newrelic.com).